# Use regular expressions with Glib

Tags: regex, gtk, glib

I would like to find all comment blocks(/*...*/) but the function g_regex_match_full always returns true.
Here is the code :

```
// Create the regex.
start_block_comment_regex = g_regex_new("/\*.*\*/", G_REGEX_OPTIMIZE, 0, &regex_error);

//Search the regex;
if(TRUE == g_regex_match_full(start_block_comment_regex, current_line, -1, 0, 0, &match_info, &regex_error))
{
}
```

Comment: Use if you this snippet, note that the documentation for the last parameter says, "Note that if match_info is not NULL then it is created even if the function returns FALSE, i.e. you must free it regardless if regular expression actually matched."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the pattern you think you are. You have to escape backslashes in strings in C:

```
comment_regex = g_regex_new("/\\*.*\\*/", G_REGEX_OPTIMIZE, 0, &regex_error);
```

I'm surprised you don't get compiler warnings about "undefined escape sequence `\*`" from your current code. I'm also surprised you didn't get errors from glib there - the pattern you effectively used was probably `/*.**/`, which doesn't make much sense. (Did you check regex_error? Obviously didn't if that's the full code...)